# How do I combine multiple between arguments

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to create an extra column in a table. The aim is to give all rows with postcodes between 2900 AND 3199 OR 2600 AND 2699 the value "Omgeving Rotterdam", all other postcodes "Nederland" and all the rows with an empty cell "No Postcode".

I tried the following code (but it gives me "Omgeving Rotterdam in all cells of the added row')

```
SELECT *
,case 
    when (LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199 OR 2600 AND 2699) then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
    when (LEFT(Postcode,4) IS NOT NULL AND NOT between 2900 AND 3199 OR 2600 AND 2699) then 'Nederland'
    else 'Geen Postcode'
end
as 'Komt Uit'
FROM
    a
        LEFT JOIN
    b ON a.ID = b.code
        JOIN
    c ON c.id_E = a.E_ID
```

Comment: when (LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199 OR LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2600 AND 2699)?

Comment: I would be tempted to store the postcodes in a more normalized manner - it would simplify the query, and greatly accelerate the process of retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe you need to specify each AND/OR step completely resulting in the following:

```
SELECT *
,case 
    when (LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199 OR LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2600 AND 2699) then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
    when (LEFT(Postcode,4) IS NOT NULL AND LEFT(Postcode,4) NOT between 2900 AND 3199 OR LEFT(Postcode,4) NOT between 2600 AND 2699) then 'Nederland'
    else 'Geen Postcode'
end
as 'Komt Uit'
FROM
    a
        LEFT JOIN
    b ON a.ID = b.code
        JOIN
    c ON c.id_E = a.E_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. Just for the explanation:

```
when (LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199 OR 2600 AND 2699) then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
```

is

```
when LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199
  OR (2600 AND 2699) then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
```

2600 is not a condition really, and 2699 is neither. But MySQL expectiing some condition there converts the integers to booleans (making 0 = false, other numbers = true). So you have:

```
when LEFT(Postcode,4) between 2900 AND 3199
  OR (true AND true) then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
```

which is merely

```
when true then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
```

This is why all your results are 'Omgeving Rotterdam'.

As to:

```
when (LEFT(Postcode,4) IS NOT NULL AND NOT between 2900 AND 3199 OR 2600 AND 2699) then 'Nederland'
```

I think that should raise an error. I don't know what mySQL's parser makes of `AND <nothing> NOT between 2900 AND 3199`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `postcode` is a *string* and not a *number*.  You should not be mixing your types.  It can be inefficient and sometimes lead to inefficient results.

In your case, you are using `LEFT()`, but this isn't actually needed for strings of the same length.  So this  will likely do what you want:

```
select *,
       (case when (Postcode >= '2900' and Postcode < '3200') or
                  (Postcode >= '2600' and Postcode < 
 '2700')
             then 'Omgeving Rotterdam'
             when post is null
             then 'Geen Postcode'
             else 'Nederland'
        end) as Komt_Uit
from a join
     c
     on c.id_E = a.E_ID left join
     b
     on a.ID = b.code;
```

Notes:

- If `postcode` does have variable lengths, then you probably want `left()`, but you might want to inspect the data.
- If `postcode` is a number, use numeric operations or include an *explicit* cast to a string.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them to define column aliases.  This will eventually lead to bugs and confusion.
- When mixing `left join` and `inner join`, I always put the `inner join` first.